# Old image swap script not working with latest jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, swap

Need help with an updated version, this is not working with jQuery 1.9

```
$(function(){
  $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Live` is depreciated I believe. Use `on` instead. This is clearly stated by the way in the jQuery documentation right near the top of the `live` page. Always a good idea in my experience to not use the latest jquery if pulling from Google, but to pick a version and stick with that. Otherwise when jQuery updates, you code could break without warning. Speaking from experieince.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

The .live method has been removed in jQuery version 1.9.  Use .on() instead to bind elements to events.  Your code would look like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do the delegated variant of `.on`, otherwise it will behave like `.bind` not `.live`. Something like `('#container').on('click', '.img-swap', function(){...})` I think?